# Multiple style headings in single CSS style sheet without changing HTML

Tags: html, css

I am working on a CSS style sheet for a class. I am supposed to create one style sheet for these three separate pages that are supposed to look like this
[CSS 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O1fx.jpg)

[CSS 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzT0m.jpg)

I am NOT allowed to change the HTML so I can't add a class. There are 5 H3 headings in the pictures Grading, Powers of 2, Purpose..., Objectives...., Logarithms..., 3 of them are on the left with no background color (log, powers, grading), and two that are on the right with background color (Objectives and Purpose). I can not figure out how to get these to look different without changing the HTML to distinguish between them. That is not all the HTML just part of it.

```
    <div>
        <h3>Purpose of the Course </h3>
        <p>This course is designed for undergraduate students in computer science and is intended to introduce them to client-side web development. The course covers the most commonly used languages for client-side web development: <strong>HTML</strong> for the structure of webpages, <strong>CSS</strong> for styling webpages, and <strong>JavaScript</strong> to make webpages dynamic and interactive as well as for client-side programming.</p>    
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>Objectives and Desired Student outcomes </h3>
        <p>Upon completion of this course, the student should be able to:</p>
            <ol>
                <li>Understand the fundamental concepts of web development.</li>
                <li>Create webpages written in HTML.</li>
                <li>Style webpages with CSS.</li>
                <li>Utilize JavaScript to make webpages dynamic and interactive.</li>
            </ol>    
    </div>

*******************************************************************************************************

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Grading</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="hw3_style1.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Grading</h3>
    <table>
        <tr><th rowspan="2" colspan="2">part</th><th colspan="2">score</th></tr>
        <tr> <th>points</th> <th>percentage</th></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="2">exam</td> 
            <td>midterm</td><td>100</td> <td>16.7%</td></tr>
            <td>final</td><td>150</td> <td>25%</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2">assignments</td> <td>250</td><td>41.7%</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2">participation</td> <td>100</td><td>16.7%</td></tr>
        <tr><th colspan="2">total</th> <th>600</th><th>100</th></tr>
    </table>
    <nav>
        <a href="cs3120intro.html">home</a>
        <a href="grading.html">grading</a>
        <a href="useful.html">useful info</a>
    </nav>
        
</body>

*******************************************************************************************************

h1{
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 300%;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ;
            text-shadow: 8px 8px 6px dimgrey;
        }

        div{
            height: 200px;
            text-align: left;
            position: relative;
            border-color: skyblue;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 2px;
            }

            h3{
                margin-top: 0px;
                background-color: skyblue;
                font-size: large;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                padding: .2em;
                margin-left: .5em;
                margin-bottom: .5em;
                float: right;
                text-align: center;
                height: 50px;
                width: 350px;
        }

            
            P{
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: medium;
            }
            ol{
                font-size: medium;
                font-style: italic;
            }
            a:hover {
                background-color: blue;
                color: beige;
                text-decoration-color: beige;

            }
            a{
                margin-top: 50px;
                margin-left: 0px;
                margin-right: 10px;
                border-color: skyblue;
                padding-left: 50px;
                padding-right: 50px;
                padding-bottom: 10px;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                height: 300px;
                width: 200px;
                background-color: skyblue;
                font-size: large;
                text-align: center;

            }
        }    
        th{
            background-color: seagreen;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can individually select elements on a page using the **:nth-child()** selector in CSS. For example, if in your page your h3 tags were aligned as so:

```
content
h3
content
content
h3  <------ Select this one
content
h3
```

You simply count the order the h3 tag is on the web page, if its the second tag, you use 2, as seen below:

```
h3:nth-child(2) {
color: green;
}
```

As seen in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7q8ks9xr/)

HTML

```
<h3>
First
</h3>
<h3>
Second
</h3>
<h3>
Third
</h3>
<h3>
Fourth
</h3>
```

CSS

```
h3:nth-child(2) {
  color: green;
}

h3:nth-child(3) {
  color: red;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Hope this answered your question! Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the tip unfortunately that only sort of worked. I tried both nth Child and nth of type. I colored them all differently so I could see what was affected. So currently on the first page, they are both green and float left, on the second page, it is also green and floated left. on the third page, one is green and one is red and they are both left. What I need basically to happen( if you couldn't see the pictures), is for the two on the first page to both be blue and floated right, all the rest need to be floated elect with white or no background.

Comment: is it possible that doesnt work over multiple pages? I'm trying to make a single style sheet for three separate webpages.

Answer (score 0):

> I can not figure out how to get these to look different

They aren't siblings, it's easy - `h3` and `section h3` can be styled different.
I replaced `div` with `section` - for semantics reasons. ... and I changed colours (kind of hobby - guessing without color-picker).

```css
hr{ margin: 30vh}
*{ box-sizing: border-box}
body{
color: #000;
background: #fff;
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h1{
text-align: center;
font-size: 2em;
text-shadow: 8px 8px 6px dimgrey;
}
h3{
font-size: 1.5em;
}
section h3{
text-align: center;
background: lightblue;
color: #025;
margin: 0 0 1em 1em;
padding: 1em 2em;
max-width: 50vw;
float: right;
}
section{
border: 2px solid lightblue;
margin: 20px;
padding: 0
}
p{
font-size: 1em;
padding: 2em;
}
ol{
font-style: italic;
}
nav{
margin: 2vh 0
}
a{
margin: 1vw;
padding: 10px;
width: 200px;
background: lightblue;
font-size: 1.1em;
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
color: #025;
}
a:hover{
background-color: darkblue;
color: #fff;
}
th{
background-color: #ae8;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
}
th, td{
border: 1px solid #000
}
```

```html
<h1>Welcome to CS1234</h1><h1>Client-side Web Programming Course</h1>
<section>
<h3>Purpose of the Course </h3>
<p>This course is designed for undergraduate students in computer science and is intended to introduce them to client-side web development. The course covers the most commonly used languages for client-side web development: <strong>HTML</strong> for the structure of webpages, <strong>CSS</strong> for styling webpages, and <strong>JavaScript</strong> to make webpages dynamic and interactive as well as for client-side programming.</p>    
</section><section>
<h3>Objectives and Desired Student outcomes </h3>
<p>Upon completion of this course, the student should be able to:</p>
<ol>
<li>Understand the fundamental concepts of web development.</li>
<li>Create webpages written in HTML.</li>
<li>Style webpages with CSS.</li>
<li>Utilize JavaScript to make webpages dynamic and interactive.</li>
</ol>    
</section>
<nav>
<a href="cs3120intro.html">home</a>
<a href="grading.html">grading</a>
<a href="useful.html">useful info</a>
</nav>

<hr>

<h3>Grading</h3>
<table><tr>
<th rowspan="2" colspan="2">part</th>
<th colspan="2">score</th>
</tr><tr>
<th>points</th>
<th>percentage</th>
</tr><tr>
<td rowspan="2">exam</td> 
<td>midterm</td>
<td>100</td>
<td>16.7%</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>final</td>
<td>150</td>
<td>25%</td>
</tr><tr>
<td colspan="2">assignments</td>
<td>250</td>
<td>41.7%</td>
</tr><tr>
<td colspan="2">participation</td>
<td>100</td>
<td>16.7%</td>
</tr><tr>
<th colspan="2">total</th>
<th>600</th><th>100</th>
</tr></table>
<nav>
<a href="cs3120intro.html">home</a>
<a href="grading.html">grading</a>
<a href="useful.html">useful info</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! This fixed it! Like I said above I'm not allowed to change the HTML and since all the online solutions involved changing the HTML I was really itching to do it anyway and hope he didn't notice.

Comment: This is web ... course - insist on replacing `div` with `section`. Semantics!